# What is the name of this game that this character is from that features clones and an older man?

Tags: game-identification

I keep seeing this game everywhere but I can’t find the name of it. I believe it has a bunch of clones or something and an old guy.

I have one image and I believe the game is fairly popular.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Judging by that image it's [Detroit: Become Human](https://www.quanticdream.com/en/detroit-become-human), and that character is [Connor](https://detroit-become-human.fandom.com/wiki/Connor), the RK800 type android (it's written in his clothes in your image, fyi).